# How to reduce my redundant code, creating generic methods?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a code to insert and update entities, but the logic are very similar: instance a controller, validate de request, if error, resturns Failed, else execute the operation.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Method Add with similar code in Update method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PersonResponse Add(PersonInsertRequest item)
        {
            var result = new PersonResponse();

            var controller = new PersonController(classmates);

            result.Messages = controller.ValidateInsert(item);

            if (result.Messages != null && result.Messages.Any())
            {
                result.Status = "failed";
            }
            else
            {
                result = controller.ExecuteInsert(item);
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method Update with similar code in Add method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PersonResponse Update(PersonUpdateRequest item)
        {
            var result = new PersonResponse();

            var controller = new PersonController(classmates);

            result.Messages = controller.ValidateUpdate(item);

            if (result.Messages != null && result.Messages.Any())
            {
                result.Status = "failed";
            }
            else
            {
                result = controller.ExecuteUpdate(item);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

-
I have tried to use delegates, but I can't use them, because I cannot assign a delegate to controller.ValidateInsert(item);

```cs
public class BaseLogic
    {
        public delegate List<Message> Validator(BaseRequest request);

        public delegate BaseResponse Executor(BaseRequest request);

        public BaseResponse Execute(BaseRequest request, Validator funcValidator, Executor funcExecutor)
        {
            var result = new BaseResponse();

            result.Messages = funcValidator(request);

            if (result.Messages != null && result.Messages.Any())
            {
                result.Status = "failed";
            }
            else
            {
                result = funcExecutor(request);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I want to reduce Add method and Update method in another more generic.

Comment: One thing that you could do to get rid of your redundant code is to combine the functions into AddOrUpdate()

Comment: I have many inherited classes with the same behavior, and more operations: validate-execute

Comment: What I'd do it to make some enum parameter that allows you to specify the action. That way your code is easy-to-read and easy-to-use.

Comment: The "production" code is an API Rest, with a lot of methods with the best-practices pattern: validate-execute

Comment: I don't understand why you're answering your own question tho... Are you farming reputation?!

Comment: @DutchJelly: No, I am not. Just I was investigating my problem solutions, and I found it, I found one, and Vivek-natarajan found one that looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my generic method in my base class, I can refactorize my methods

```cs
/// <summary>
        /// Method Add with similar code in Update method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PersonResponse Add(PersonInsertRequest item)
        {

            var controller = new PersonController(classmates);

            Validator myValidator = request => controller.ValidateInsert((PersonInsertRequest)request);
            Executor myExecutor = request => controller.ExecuteInsert((PersonInsertRequest)request);

            var result = Execute(item, myValidator, myExecutor);

            return result as PersonResponse;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method Update with similar code in Add method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PersonResponse Update(PersonUpdateRequest item)
        {
            var controller = new PersonController(classmates);

            Validator myValidator = request => controller.ValidateUpdate((PersonUpdateRequest)request);
            Executor myExecutor = request => controller.ExecuteUpdate((PersonUpdateRequest)request);

            var result = Execute(item, myValidator, myExecutor);

            return result as PersonResponse;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    private object classmates;

public PersonResponse Add(PersonInsertRequest item)
{
    var controller = new PersonController(classmates);
    return ValidateAndExecute(() => controller.ValidateInsert(item),
    () => controller.ExecuteInsert(item));
}

public PersonResponse Update(PersonUpdateRequest item)
{
    var controller = new PersonController(classmates);
    return ValidateAndExecute(() => controller.ValidateUpdate(item),
    () => controller.ExecuteUpdate(item));
}

private PersonResponse ValidateAndExecute(Func<IEnumerable<string>> validator,
Func<PersonResponse> execute)
{
    var result = new PersonResponse();

    result.Messages = validator();

    if (result.Messages != null && result.Messages.Any())
    {
        result.Status = "failed";
    }
    else
    {
        result = execute();
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Let me implement it

Comment: When I implemented in clases with BaseResponse, it results with a lot of "casting" errors.